# how to get count of products that are not stored yet in mysql

Tags: mysql

hello i have an order_table with product_code that this product_code has no relation with another table and is populating directly from my app i have 8 product_code in my app and i want to get count of all product per order  like this from order_table

```
prodouct_code|count
code1        |     5
code2        |     0    
code3        |     2    
code4        |     0    
....    
code8        |     4
```

but i only can get the count of existing products.. is there any way to get them all ?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: what do you tried?

Comment: Don't like show us any code or anything

Comment: sry guys what i was tring was so Stereotype

Comment: @hamiidrezaGholami Look at the bright side, Gordon got 10 more points out of this (because I upvoted him after he posted first ha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably more easily done in your application.  But, you can do it in MySQL.  The normal method is to have a table with one row per product:

```
select p.productcode, count(o.productcode)
from products p left join
     orders o
     on p.productcode = o.productcode
group by p.productcode;
```

If you don't have such a table, you should probably create one.  But, you can do what you want by using a derived table in the query:

```
select p.productcode, count(o.productcode)
from (select 1 as productcode union all
      select 2 union all
      . . . 
      select 8
     ) p left join
     orders o
     on p.productcode = o.productcode
group by p.productcode;
```

Comment: oh ty man i am really greau full to your answer . i got the idea .

Comment: sry that i can give you +1